# problems with multiple commands in one batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to write patch file starting in batch and with to convert that to exe once completed.

i have 2 batch files that work just great when executed separately but when i join them in one the 2nd part of batch file (that joined one) is not completion task (not adding registry entries).

can you please have look on bellow batch and let me know where i did make mistake (be aware this is application specific )

thanks you in advance

error 1st part is deleting directories and moving files however 2dn is not creating registry entries please help

```
comd /c
@echo ofF
xcopy /y C:\ProgramData\Jeppesen\Common\TerminalChartsTemp
C:\ProgramData\Jeppesen\Common\TerminalCharts
rmdir /s /q C:\ProgramData\Jeppesen\Common\TerminalCharts.0.0
rmdir /s /q C:\ProgramData\Jeppesen\Common\TerminalCharts.alt.0
rmdir /s /q C:\ProgramData\Jeppesen\Common\TerminalChartsTemp



; @echo ofF
; CLS
; REGEDIT.EXE /S "%~f0"
; EXIT

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Jeppesen\JeppView for Windows\Paths]
"CommonHidden"="C:\\ProgramData\\Jeppesen\\Common\\"
"C2E_config"="C:\\ProgramData\\Jeppesen\\Common\\C2E4\\Config\\"
"C2E_data"="C:\\ProgramData\\Jeppesen\\Common\\C2E4\\Data1\\"
"ShapeData"="C:\\ProgramData\\Jeppesen\\Common\\C2E4\\Cultural\\"
"TerrainData"="C:\\ProgramData\\Jeppesen\\Common\\TerrainData\\"
"Themes"="C:\\ProgramData\\Jeppesen\\JeppView for Windows\\Themes\\"
"Logs"="C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Jeppesen\\JeppView for Windows\\Logs\\"
"Bitmaps"="C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Jeppesen\\JeppView for Windows\\Bitmaps\\"
"TerminalCharts"="C:\\ProgramData\\Jeppesen\\Common\\TerminalCharts\\"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Jeppesen\Jeppesen e-Link for Windows\Paths]
"CommonHidden"="C:\\ProgramData\\Jeppesen\\Common\\"
"C2E_config"="C:\\ProgramData\\Jeppesen\\Common\\C2E4\\Config\\"
"C2E_data"="C:\\ProgramData\\Jeppesen\\Common\\C2E4\\Data1\\"
"ShapeData"="C:\\ProgramData\\Jeppesen\\Common\\C2E4\\Cultural\\"
"TerrainData"="C:\\ProgramData\\Jeppesen\\Common\\TerrainData\\"
"Themes"="C:\\ProgramData\\Jeppesen\\Jeppesen e-Link for Windows\\Themes\\"
"Logs"="C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Jeppesen\\Jeppesen e-Link for Windows\\Logs\\"
"Bitmaps"="C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Jeppesen\\Jeppesen e-Link for Windows\\Bitmaps\\"
"TerminalCharts"="C:\\ProgramData\\Jeppesen\\Common\\TerminalCharts\\"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying [to use batch/reg hybrid file](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/regedit.php#Self-contained).So you need to comment (from reg syntax point of view) batch sections with `;`  and to put the registry tag at the beginning :

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

;@cls
;@echo ofF
;xcopy /y "C:\ProgramData\Jeppesen\Common\TerminalChartsTemp" "C:\ProgramData\Jeppesen\Common\TerminalCharts"
;rmdir /s /q C:\ProgramData\Jeppesen\Common\TerminalCharts.0.0
;rmdir /s /q C:\ProgramData\Jeppesen\Common\TerminalCharts.alt.0
;rmdir /s /q C:\ProgramData\Jeppesen\Common\TerminalChartsTemp



; REGEDIT.EXE /S "%~f0"
; EXIT /b 0

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Jeppesen\JeppView for Windows\Paths]
"CommonHidden"="C:\\ProgramData\\Jeppesen\\Common\\"
"C2E_config"="C:\\ProgramData\\Jeppesen\\Common\\C2E4\\Config\\"
"C2E_data"="C:\\ProgramData\\Jeppesen\\Common\\C2E4\\Data1\\"
"ShapeData"="C:\\ProgramData\\Jeppesen\\Common\\C2E4\\Cultural\\"
"TerrainData"="C:\\ProgramData\\Jeppesen\\Common\\TerrainData\\"
"Themes"="C:\\ProgramData\\Jeppesen\\JeppView for Windows\\Themes\\"
"Logs"="C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Jeppesen\\JeppView for Windows\\Logs\\"
"Bitmaps"="C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Jeppesen\\JeppView for Windows\\Bitmaps\\"
"TerminalCharts"="C:\\ProgramData\\Jeppesen\\Common\\TerminalCharts\\"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Jeppesen\Jeppesen e-Link for Windows\Paths]
"CommonHidden"="C:\\ProgramData\\Jeppesen\\Common\\"
"C2E_config"="C:\\ProgramData\\Jeppesen\\Common\\C2E4\\Config\\"
"C2E_data"="C:\\ProgramData\\Jeppesen\\Common\\C2E4\\Data1\\"
"ShapeData"="C:\\ProgramData\\Jeppesen\\Common\\C2E4\\Cultural\\"
"TerrainData"="C:\\ProgramData\\Jeppesen\\Common\\TerrainData\\"
"Themes"="C:\\ProgramData\\Jeppesen\\Jeppesen e-Link for Windows\\Themes\\"
"Logs"="C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Jeppesen\\Jeppesen e-Link for Windows\\Logs\\"
"Bitmaps"="C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Jeppesen\\Jeppesen e-Link for Windows\\Bitmaps\\"
"TerminalCharts"="C:\\ProgramData\\Jeppesen\\Common\\TerminalCharts\\"
```