# Creating a folder and registry editing script as an executable

Tags: batch-file, window

I have bat (working 100%) file but but when I compile this as an exe it is losing its registry entry functionality.

Can you recommend rewriting the code to a different langauge that can be converted to exe, would that be more difficult ?

Bat file needs to copy, delete folder directories and rearrange registry entries

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

;@cls
;@echo ofF
;xcopy /y "C:\ProgramData\Jeppesen\Common\TerminalChartsTemp"    "C:\ProgramData\Jeppesen\Common\TerminalCharts"
;rmdir /s /q C:\ProgramData\Jeppesen\Common\TerminalCharts.0.0
;rmdir /s /q C:\ProgramData\Jeppesen\Common\TerminalCharts.alt.0
;rmdir /s /q C:\ProgramData\Jeppesen\Common\TerminalChartsTemp

; REGEDIT.EXE /S "%~f0"
; EXIT /b 0

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Jeppesen\JeppView for Windows\Paths]
"CommonHidden"="C:\\ProgramData\\Jeppesen\\Common\\"
"C2E_config"="C:\\ProgramData\\Jeppesen\\Common\\C2E4\\Config\\"
"C2E_data"="C:\\ProgramData\\Jeppesen\\Common\\C2E4\\Data1\\"
"ShapeData"="C:\\ProgramData\\Jeppesen\\Common\\C2E4\\Cultural\\"
"TerrainData"="C:\\ProgramData\\Jeppesen\\Common\\TerrainData\\"
"Themes"="C:\\ProgramData\\Jeppesen\\JeppView for Windows\\Themes\\"
"Logs"="C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Jeppesen\\JeppView for Windows\\Logs\\"
"Bitmaps"="C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Jeppesen\\JeppView for Windows\\Bitmaps\\"
"TerminalCharts"="C:\\ProgramData\\Jeppesen\\Common\\TerminalCharts\\"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Jeppesen\Jeppesen e-Link for Windows\Paths]
"CommonHidden"="C:\\ProgramData\\Jeppesen\\Common\\"
"C2E_config"="C:\\ProgramData\\Jeppesen\\Common\\C2E4\\Config\\"
"C2E_data"="C:\\ProgramData\\Jeppesen\\Common\\C2E4\\Data1\\"
"ShapeData"="C:\\ProgramData\\Jeppesen\\Common\\C2E4\\Cultural\\"
"TerrainData"="C:\\ProgramData\\Jeppesen\\Common\\TerrainData\\"
"Themes"="C:\\ProgramData\\Jeppesen\\Jeppesen e-Link for Windows\\Themes\\"
"Logs"="C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Jeppesen\\Jeppesen e-Link for Windows\\Logs\\"
"Bitmaps"="C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Jeppesen\\Jeppesen e-Link for Windows\\Bitmaps\\"
"TerminalCharts"="C:\\ProgramData\\Jeppesen\\Common\\TerminalCharts\\"
```

Comment: This through me off at first until I read another post from the OP http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30779434/problems-with-multiple-comands-in-one-batch-file

Comment: Good ol' e-Link. How are you making this an EXE? And more importantly why?